# Python looking for image file using 'url_for'

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to find image file `a.jpg` from `abc` folder located `/var/www/Project/ABC/static/assets/images/abc`

And I am using `url_for`function to reach `a.jpg`

My `b.py` file located on `/var/www/Project/ABC/ccc/b.py`

How do I use `url_for` fuction here?

I have tried using `imageFile = url_for('static', filename='assets/images/abc'+ a.jpg')`

But this does not get `a.jpg` file

Can some one help?

Comment: try changing the filename to: `'static/assets/images/abc'+ str(a.jpg)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't get `a.jpg` because it's missing the path separator.

```
imageFile = url_for('static', filename='assets/images/abc' + 'a.jpg')
```

The right side of the above statement will evaluate to

```
imageFile = url_for('static', filename='assets/images/abca.jpg')
```

Import the [*path* module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) and use that to join the filename paths.

```
from os import path

imageFile = url_for('static', filename=path.join('assets', 'images', 'abc', 'a.jpg'))
```